# filtering integer column with contains

Tags: filter, grid, integer

I am trying to apply a global search filter for my grid by applying the search filters for each column:

```
filter.push(
   //strings
   { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: item },
   { field: "City", operator: "contains", value: item },
   { field: "StreetAddress", operator: "contains", value: item },

   //integers
   { field: "Zip", operator: "iscontainedin", value: item }
);

//apply filters with 'or logic' (searchterm is contained somewhere in the row)
$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
     logic: "or",
     filters: filter
});
```

This works for me, except for the columns that are not of datatype string.
I am aware that i could use the operator "isequalto" (http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc/FilterOperator) but i want a contains functionality on integers too like 1234 contains 23...

Is that possible, or is there maybe a better solution to archieve a global searchfield which can maybe apply filtering to ALL columns of a table (without setting them up manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, what i ended up doing was the following:
i added an additional field to my model which is only a concatenation of all other fields like "field1 field2 field3" and then i just use my contains filter on this field-aggregate.
this works pretty well for my needs! (hope it helps someone else...)